# ArcMap 10.5.1 search window not showing properly

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.5, windows-7, search-window

Why is ArcMap 10.5.1 search window not showing properly?

Out of ca 50 times opening ArcMap, only twice or so it looked like in previous versions, i.e. there was possibility to work with that - e.g. enter a name of function and search for it...

[image]

I am using Windows 7 Professional.

---

I have
-renamed ESRI folder, also in registry, not helped!
-deleted Normal.mxt, no change!
-chosen "repair" in instalation file window, also **not helped!**